# Asymptotics of the inverse of an analytic equation

Tags: asymptotics, lagrange-inversion

What is an asymptotics for the solution of the analytic (transcendental) equation
$$e^{-x^2}P\Big(\frac1x \Big)=\frac1y$$
where $P$ is a polynomial, as $y\rightarrow\infty$? Would the Lagrange inversion help? One difficulty of applying the Lagrange inversion theorem is that the $e^{-x^2}$ has an essential singularity at $x=\infty$.

As the first step, set $P(u) = u$.

Comment: Such an equation will have infinitely many complex solutions in general. Which ones are you interested in?

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Yes. I am interested in the branch of $x$ on the real axis. In particular for the first example of $P(u)=u$, I want positive $x$. Of course if you have the solution for other branches, I would like to see them too.

Comment: If $P(u) = u^k$ then the equation can be solved exactly as $$x = \pm \sqrt{\frac{k}{2} \operatorname{W}\!\left(\frac{2}{k} y^{2/k}\right)},$$ where $\operatorname W$ is any branch of the Lambert W function. You can then use the known asymptotics for that function to get asymptotics for $x$. For $u > 0$, the only real branch is $\operatorname{W}_0(u)$ with asymptotic $\operatorname{W}_0(u) \sim \ln u$, so the leading order of the positive solution is $x \sim \sqrt{(k/2)\ln y^{2/k}} = \sqrt{\ln y}$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Nice. Do you have more to say regarding the general case of a polynomial? Of course, the leading order asymptotic terms would be determined by the leading polynomial term.

Comment: How did this equation arise?

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Here is my original question https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/336145/44368 where I already give the correct upper bound of the asymptotics before the rigorous treatment given here by my answer below and your comment above. The root of it all comes from a paper that I think is wrong in treating the asymptotics. If you are interested I can give you the link to the paper and we can have a discussion on it. By the way, have you seen my answer below solving the problem directly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75011/discussion-between-hans-and-antonio-vargas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for the simplest case of $P(u)=u$.

Take logarithm of the original equation
$$x = \sqrt{\ln y-\ln x}.\tag1$$
Obviously $x>1$ for large $y$. So $x<\sqrt{\ln y}$ and $x=O(\sqrt{\ln y})$. Taking logarithm
$$\ln x = O(\ln\ln y) \tag2$$
Substitute Equation (2) into Equation (1)
$$x=\sqrt{\ln y}\Big(1+O\Big(\frac{\ln\ln y}{\ln y}\Big)\Big).$$
This is not good enough, since when substituting this expression into the origin equation we do not get the right hand side explicitly. So we iterate Equation (1) and inserting Equation (2) into it. We have
\begin{align}
x &= \sqrt{\ln y - \frac12\ln\big( \ln y-\ln x\big)} \\
&= \sqrt{\ln y - \frac12\ln\big( \ln y-O(\ln\ln y)\big)} \\
&= \sqrt{\ln y - \frac12\ln\ln y-\frac12\ln\Big(1- O\Big(\frac{\ln\ln y}{\ln y}\Big)\Big)} \\
&= \sqrt{\ln y - \frac12\ln\ln y+O\Big(\frac{\ln\ln y}{\ln y}\Big)} \\
& = \sqrt{\ln y - \frac12\ln\ln y}\,\Big(1+O\Big(\frac{\ln\ln y}{(\ln y)^2}\Big)\Big) 
\end{align}
We can continue this iteration indefinitely.

---

For the general polynomial case we can use sandwiching inequalities

$$e^{-x^2}\frac{1-\delta}x<\frac1y = e^{-x^2}\Big(\frac1x+\frac a{x^2}\Big)<e^{-x^2}\frac{1+\delta}x$$
for large enough $y$ and thus $x$. Then proceed either with the iteration procedure above or the Lambert W function as described in @AntonioVargas' comment above.